# lamp server not working

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php

LAMP server doesn't work. I didn't run any updates. It was working fine till yesterday

Here's mysql error:

````
```
2020-03-22T01:10:30.107784Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2020-03-22T01:10:30.107838Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2020-03-22T01:10:30.107843Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2020-03-22T01:10:30.107851Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2020-03-22T01:10:30.108922Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109410Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'validate_password'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109438Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'auth_socket'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109443Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109446Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109449Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109454Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109456Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109483Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109488Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109495Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109499Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109502Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109505Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109508Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109510Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109513Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109515Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109518Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109520Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109522Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109525Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109527Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109530Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109532Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109535Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109538Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109541Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109544Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109547Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109550Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109552Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109555Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109557Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109560Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109563Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109566Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109568Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109571Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109574Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109577Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2020-03-22T01:10:30.109630Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2020-03-22T01:10:30.113115Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2020-03-22T01:10:30.213295Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-03-22T01:10:30.213499Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 200322  2:10:30
2020-03-22T01:10:31.625536Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 6901839
2020-03-22T01:10:31.625771Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-03-22T01:10:31.625779Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2020-03-22T01:10:31.625783Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2020-03-22T01:10:31.625794Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2020-03-22T01:10:31.625796Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2020-03-22T01:10:31.625967Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2020-03-22T01:10:31.626177Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2020-03-22T01:12:43.605589Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-03-22T01:12:43.606803Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 1256 ...
2020-03-22T01:12:43.615954Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2020-03-22T01:12:43.615983Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-03-22T01:12:43.615988Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-03-22T01:12:43.615992Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-03-22T01:12:43.615996Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-03-22T01:12:43.616001Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-03-22T01:12:43.617224Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-03-22T01:12:43.619464Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-03-22T01:12:43.620463Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-03-22T01:12:43.627540Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-03-22T01:12:43.629738Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-03-22T01:12:43.647471Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-03-22T01:12:43.698757Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-03-22T01:12:43.698821Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-03-22T01:12:43.736172Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-03-22T01:12:43.737047Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-03-22T01:12:43.737064Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-03-22T01:12:43.737307Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-03-22T01:12:43.789363Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.29 started; log sequence number 6901839
2020-03-22T01:12:43.789683Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-03-22T01:12:43.790124Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-03-22T01:12:43.807314Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2020-03-22T01:12:43.807326Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2020-03-22T01:12:43.817179Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-03-22T01:12:43.817229Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2020-03-22T01:12:43.822829Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200322  2:12:43
2020-03-22T01:12:43.823198Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2020-03-22T01:12:43.823216Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2020-03-22T01:12:43.823240Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2020-03-22T01:12:43.887699Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-03-22T01:12:43.887880Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
2020-03-22T01:36:56.938625Z 2 [Note] Access denied for user 'brahimi'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2020-03-22T01:53:07.989578Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2020-03-22T01:53:07.989604Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2020-03-22T01:53:07.989612Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2020-03-22T01:53:07.989618Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2020-03-22T01:53:07.990480Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992511Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'validate_password'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992561Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'auth_socket'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992565Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992568Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992572Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992577Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992580Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992605Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992612Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992618Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992621Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992623Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992626Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992628Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992631Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992634Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992636Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992638Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992641Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992643Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992645Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992648Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992650Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992653Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992655Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992658Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992660Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992663Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992666Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992668Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992671Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992674Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992676Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992679Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992682Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992685Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992688Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992691Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992693Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992696Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992796Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2020-03-22T01:53:07.992943Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2020-03-22T01:53:08.093145Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-03-22T01:53:08.093514Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 200322  2:53:08
2020-03-22T01:53:09.705437Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 6901867
2020-03-22T01:53:09.706469Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-03-22T01:53:09.706477Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2020-03-22T01:53:09.706481Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2020-03-22T01:53:09.706484Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2020-03-22T01:53:09.706486Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2020-03-22T01:53:09.706622Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2020-03-22T01:53:09.706824Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2020-03-22T19:18:34.534932Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-03-22T19:18:34.536396Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 1303 ...
2020-03-22T19:18:34.542023Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2020-03-22T19:18:34.542047Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-03-22T19:18:34.542051Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-03-22T19:18:34.542054Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-03-22T19:18:34.542057Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-03-22T19:18:34.542061Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-03-22T19:18:34.542791Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-03-22T19:18:34.544887Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-03-22T19:18:34.546204Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-03-22T19:18:34.556415Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-03-22T19:18:34.558599Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-03-22T19:18:34.579015Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-03-22T19:18:34.638628Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-03-22T19:18:34.638690Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-03-22T19:18:34.678932Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-03-22T19:18:34.679548Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-03-22T19:18:34.679563Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-03-22T19:18:34.679788Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-03-22T19:18:34.729917Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.29 started; log sequence number 6901867
2020-03-22T19:18:34.730182Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-03-22T19:18:34.730191Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-03-22T19:18:34.751535Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2020-03-22T19:18:34.751556Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2020-03-22T19:18:34.755286Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-03-22T19:18:34.755329Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2020-03-22T19:18:34.757683Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2020-03-22T19:18:34.757707Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2020-03-22T19:18:34.757725Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2020-03-22T19:18:34.764592Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200322 20:18:34
2020-03-22T19:18:34.846919Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-03-22T19:18:34.847057Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)```
````

Here's php error:

````
```[12-Mar-2020 20:30:55 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in /var/www/html/testing/testphp.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/testing/testphp.php on line 5
[12-Mar-2020 20:31:00 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in /var/www/html/testing/testphp.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/testing/testphp.php on line 5
[12-Mar-2020 22:29:41 Europe/Berlin] PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/test.php on line 21
[12-Mar-2020 22:31:29 Europe/Berlin] PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/test.php on line 21
[12-Mar-2020 22:31:41 Europe/Berlin] PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/test.php on line 21
[12-Mar-2020 22:32:07 Europe/Berlin] PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/test.php on line 21
[12-Mar-2020 22:32:10 Europe/Berlin] PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/test.php on line 21
[12-Mar-2020 22:34:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/test.php on line 21
[12-Mar-2020 22:50:24 Europe/Berlin] PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/test.php on line 21
[12-Mar-2020 22:50:28 Europe/Berlin] PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/test.php on line 21
[13-Mar-2020 21:06:46 Europe/Berlin] PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/modifier.php on line 16
[14-Mar-2020 01:34:40 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ln2br() in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/modifierr.php:35
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/modifierr.php on line 35
[14-Mar-2020 01:34:50 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ln2br() in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/modifierr.php:35
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/modifierr.php on line 35
[14-Mar-2020 01:34:52 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ln2br() in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/modifierr.php:35
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/modifierr.php on line 35
[14-Mar-2020 01:34:53 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ln2br() in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/modifierr.php:35
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/modifierr.php on line 35
[14-Mar-2020 01:35:02 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ln2br() in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/modifierr.php:35
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/modifierr.php on line 35
[14-Mar-2020 01:37:22 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ln2br() in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/modifierr.php:36
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/modifierr.php on line 36
[14-Mar-2020 01:37:27 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ln2br() in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/modifierr.php:36
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/modifierr.php on line 36
[14-Mar-2020 01:39:08 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ln2br() in /var/www/html/tp_daw_1/modifierr.php:36
Stack trace:```
````

And here's the apache2 error log:

````
 ```[Sun Mar 22 00:08:53.611106 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1278] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Sun Mar 22 00:08:53.611131 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1278] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
    [Sun Mar 22 02:02:50.531188 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1278] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Sun Mar 22 02:02:50.585438 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17327] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Sun Mar 22 02:02:50.585486 2020] [core:notice] [pid 17327] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
    [Sun Mar 22 02:08:05.435924 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17327] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Sun Mar 22 02:08:05.528831 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17792] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Sun Mar 22 02:08:05.528880 2020] [core:notice] [pid 17792] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
    [Sun Mar 22 02:10:30.226130 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17792] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Sun Mar 22 02:12:43.379233 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1201] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Sun Mar 22 02:12:43.379520 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1201] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
    [Sun Mar 22 02:53:08.141295 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1201] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Sun Mar 22 20:18:34.277590 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1271] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Sun Mar 22 20:18:34.290181 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1271] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
    [Sun Mar 22 20:39:16.737289 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1271] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Sun Mar 22 20:39:16.790550 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6116] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Sun Mar 22 20:39:16.790611 2020] [core:notice] [pid 6116] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
    [Sun Mar 22 20:56:59.540798 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6116] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Sun Mar 22 20:56:59.596100 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7415] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Sun Mar 22 20:56:59.596169 2020] [core:notice] [pid 7415] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'```
````

Any ideas on how to fix it?

What do I need to check!

Comment: yes , i've tried that , didn't work , so the problem is with php ? can it be a port problem !

Comment: okay , i see then what's causing it ?

Comment: the first command gave this  ```Failed to stop httpd.service: Unit httpd.service not loaded.``` the second gave this      ``` AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105856/discussion-between-brahimi-ahmed-farouk-and-gryu).